# How do I create a object in a static constant helper class with void set methods?

Tags: java

So I have object

```java
@Data
public class Bicycle{
     private String color;
     private long speed;
     private String tag;

    public Bicycle(String color, long speed){
         color = color;
         speed = speed;   
    }

    public void setTag(String tag){
        tag = tag;
    }
}
```

I also have a Helper class that contains all my constants where I store a Bicycle I want to reference alot. I want to add a Bicylce with color="blue",speed=5L,tag="mountain" as a public static variable but I'm not sure how to do that since the constructor doesnt use tag, and setTag returns void. I don't own this Bicycle class so I can't add it to the constructor.

```java
public class Helper{
   public static final Bicycle = new Bicycle("blue",5L);

}
```

Because of this, whenever I have to create this bicycle

```java
     main{
         Bicycle bicycle = Helper.Bicycle;
         Bicycle.setTag"mountain");
   }
```

How would I create this bicycle with the "mountain" tag in the Helper class?

Comment: your compiler should display a warning at `tag = tag;`, something like "Assignment has no effect". That is because the parameter shadows the field, and you have to explicitly specify what you mean with `this.tag = tag;` (same for the other fields).

Comment: use `this.color = color` and `this.speed = speed` and `this.tag = tag`

Comment: You should fix the code so that it works otherwise than what your answer is. Like this: `public static final Bicycle = new Bicycle("blue",5L);`

Comment: Adding another constructor to `Bicycle` that takes an additional "tag" parameter would solve the issue nicely.   If you're unwilling to do that, however, a static initializer block, as many have suggested, will save the day.

Comment: There is a fundamental problem with the idea to have “constants” in a helper class that have methods allowing to modify them.

Answer (score 7):

Add a `static` block in  your `Helper` like:

```
public class Helper {
    public static final Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle("blue", 5L);
    static {
        bicycle.setTag("mountain");
    }
}
```

And fix the assignments like `tag = tag` -> `this.tag = tag`.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a static block into your helper class to do more stuff you cannot do when you instantiate your object.

```java
public class Helper {
   public static final Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle("Blue", 5L);

   static {
      bicycle.setTag("mountain");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its returning void because you aren't really assigning properly

```
    @Data
public class Bicycle{
     private String color;
     private long speed;
     private String tag;

    public Bicycle(String color, long speed){
         this.color = color;
         this.speed = speed;   
    }

    public void setTag(String tag){
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

your helper class

```
     public class Helper{
       public static final Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle("blue",5L);
         static{
           bicycle.setTag("mountain");
}
    
    }
```

Comment: When you will open the declaration of `this.color`, it will direct you to `private String color`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I would suggest you use is the factory pattern.  It's like what you're doing, but your helper class would expose a method rather than a static variable.  So you might have:

```
public class Helper{
    private static Bicycle bicycle = null;
    public static Bicycle getBlueMountainBike() {
        if (bicycle == null) {
            bicycle = new Bicycle("blue", 5L);
            bicycle.setTag"mountain");
        }
        return bicycle;
    }
}

main{
     Bicycle bicycle = Helper.getBlueMountainBike();
}
```

I very much like the other answers that add the `static` block to solve the problem while keeping the original API.

The factory method approach does have one advantage that could be significant in specific applications.  Say you've got a helper class like this with 100 such constants, say many types of vehicles, bikes and other things.  And say that any particular application of the helper class uses just a few of the many constants in the helper.  With the factory approach, you save the time and space of constructing all of those other objects that will never be used.

Comment: I believe the solution with the static block is superior.

Comment: I won't argue with that, although I think it's mostly a matter of preferred style.

Comment: Well, with your variant you will always have to call `getBicycle()` and you lose the `final`-tag.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I said I wouldn't argue with your statement.  I still think that if you would rather call a method, there's nothing wrong with either approach.  There's certainly no reason to not have your code read the way you prefer just to save a few microseconds of execution time.

Comment: @CodingTil neither variant is recommendable. It makes no difference whether anyone everywhere can invoke `Helper.bicycle.setTag("whatever they want");` or `Helper.getBlueMountainBike().setTag("whatever they want");` to bring the application into an inconsistent state. Shared “constants” and public setter methods are incompatible in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a static factory function:

```
public class Helper{
   public static final blueMountainbike = createBicycle("blue", 5L, "mountain");

   public static Bicycle createBicycle(String color, long speed, String tag) {
       Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle(color, speed);
       bicycle.setTag(tag);
       return bicycle;
   }
}
```

This has the advantage that it can be reused to create different bicycles.

---

Side note: try to come up with a better name for `Helper`. If the main puprose is creating and accessing instances of bicyles, `BicycleFactory` might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

this return **void** because you aren't assigning properly. your helper class would expose a method rather than a static variable

```
    @Data
public class Bicycle{
     private String color;
     private long speed;
     private String tag;

    public Bicycle(String color, long speed){
         this.color = color;
         this.speed = speed;   
    }

    public void setTag(String tag){
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

your helper class

```
     public class Helper{
       public static final Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle("blue",5L);
         static{
           bicycle.setTag("mountain");
}
    
    }
```

read this if you are beginner [use this. in java](https://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword)

Comment: use this.tag = tag